# gulp pipe.watch is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, watch

When i run this code

```
    var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');    

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
    .pipe(watch('./lib/*.js'))  
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))           
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

this code builds without error but the program it is not finished

Comment: It's not going to "finish" because you're using `watch`, which keeps the process open to check for file changes.

Comment: @Ben Fortune thanks and sorry for misunderstaing